# Python deployment to Azure App Service fails without error

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a Python application which runs without issue locally through vscode and using `flask run`.

When I try the following command to push the application to Azure, it fails:

```
(.venv) C:\MOS>az webapp up --sku B1 --name mechanics-of-search-api --location "North Europe" -g "mechanics-of-search"
The webapp 'mechanics-of-search-api' doesn't exist
Creating AppServicePlan 'michaelryan998_asp_Linux_northeurope_0' ...
Creating webapp 'mechanics-of-search-api' ...
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Creating zip with contents of dir C:\MOS ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Zip deployment failed. {'id': '748e8415-1c27-484e-94e6-0855a5b6de60', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'Push-Deployer', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2021-04-12T17:47:20.5128971Z', 'start_time': '2021-04-12T17:47:21.7678719Z', 'end_time': '2021-04-12T17:47:50.2735201Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 'url': 'https://mechanics-of-search-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://mechanics-of-search-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'mechanics-of-search-api'}. Please run the command az webapp log deployment show -n mechanics-of-search-api -g mechanics-of-search
```

When I try to open the logs at `https://mechanics-of-search-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log`:

```
{"ClassName":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","Message":"No log found for 'latest'.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Core/Deployment/DeploymentManager.cs:line 112\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services/Deployment/DeploymentController.cs:line 432","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2147024894,"Source":"Kudu.Core","WatsonBuckets":null,"FileNotFound_FileName":null,"FileNotFound_FusionLog":null}
```

And if I execute `az webapp log deployment show -n mechanics-of-search-api -g mechanics-of-search`

```
[
  {
    "details_url": null,
    "id": "a8aa2668-bd08-4617-a48a-731ebd815823",
    "log_time": "2021-04-12T17:47:20.6319438Z",
    "message": "Updating submodules.",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "details_url": null,
    "id": "2bebee7b-51a9-4f29-8c23-9ccefbc1c17d",
    "log_time": "2021-04-12T17:47:21.7065948Z",
    "message": "Preparing deployment for commit id '748e8415-1'.",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "details_url": null,
    "id": "9cd7ebd1-6aea-4feb-ad90-7461644968dc",
    "log_time": "2021-04-12T17:47:21.9512376Z",
    "message": "Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "details_url": "https://mechanics-of-search-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/748e8415-1c27-484e-94e6-0855a5b6de60/log/69a4b157-8ddc-492a-ba84-d000bbb545dc",
    "id": "69a4b157-8ddc-492a-ba84-d000bbb545dc",
    "log_time": "2021-04-12T17:47:22.0239278Z",
    "message": "Running oryx build...",
    "type": 2
  }
]
```

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
app==1.0 #Locally defined modules in the project
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
joblib==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
nltk==3.6.1
numpy==1.20.2
progressbar2==3.53.1
python-utils==2.5.6
regex==2021.4.4
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
tqdm==4.60.0
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wikipedia==1.4.0
```

I've no idea what's run or how to go about finding where the error lies. I was successfully able to deploy the [sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask). The project is about 140MB.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the first step in troubleshooting is to use App Service Diagnostics:

On the Azure portal for your web app, select **Diagnose and solve problems** from the left menu.
Select **Availability and performance**.
Examine the information in the **Application Logs, Container crash,** and **Container Issues options**, where the most common issues will appear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#troubleshooting

**Additional considerations**

1. Make sure you are in the right folder. `az webapp` up should be run
   from the local folder containing your code. The most common mistake
   is running the command in the parent directory.
2. Confirm your project
   structure complies with requirements outlined in the the "Automatic
   Runtime Detection Logic" section below.
3. Still having issues? Create
   an issue in our repository:
   https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/issues